# Getting row number of approximate VLOOKUP match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two large lists which I would like to compare. I want to know which cells have stayed the exact same and which cells have been modified slightly but are an "approximate" match. I am currently using a VLOOKUP to check if the cells are exactly the same and using a match function to check which row the counterpart is in. However, for the approximate match I want to know the same thing but I have not been able to find an answer. Therefore, my questions is it possible to get the row number of approximate VLOOKUP match and if not, is there another way of doing it without the use of VBA?

Column B: `=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Rev 1]],F2:$F$4,1,FALSE),"")<>"","Same","Change")`

Column C: `=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Rev 1]],F2:$F$4,1,TRUE),"")<>"",IF([@[Exact Match]]="Same","Same","Approx. the same"),"Change")`

Column D: `=IFERROR(MATCH([@[Rev 1]],$F$2:$F$4,0),"")`

Comment: The answer is probably "Yes". But if you can edit your question to include sample data with expected results and your own attempted formula for debugging purposes, I'm sure you can get more detailed help. See [ask] a question with a [mcve].

Comment: Likely you could do this using two matches - one for matches greater or equal and the other for less than or equal...

Comment: Its not what I wanted, but I just used the result of an approximate VLOOKUP and then converted this to Yes or No depending on whether it was an error or not.

Comment: Are you looking for text strings that are slightly off, or a number value that is closest to the search string? In case of text, look into Excel fuzzy lookup addin https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011 otherwise MATCH can do the trick, but we need some sample data to match your case

Comment: This may be helpful for numeric closest match: `=MATCH(MIN(ABS(A1:A10-B1)),(ABS(A1:A10-B1)),0)` https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9le7.jpg needs entered with `ctrl+shift+enter` in older Excel versions

Comment: If you can use `XLOOKUP` you could just wrap it in the `Row()` function as it returns a reference to the cell and not just the value.